# Output from MysSQL query to xml file

Tags: php

I have this code i am trying to create a sitemap from and i need some help. When i run the php file i get the output of the file on the screen but no sitemap.xml file is created, anyone know why ?

```
<?

$xmlfile = 'sitemap.xml';

// this variable will contain the XML sitemap that will be saved in $xmlfile
$xmlsitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">';

// Connection data (server_address, name, password, database_name)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$userdb = 'user';
$passdb = 'ps';
$namedb = 'db';

try {
  // Connect and create the PDO object
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
  $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

  // Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
  $sql = "SELECT id, shortUrl FROM shorturl WHERE id BETWEEN 15 AND 45000";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
  if($result !== false) {
    // Parse the result set, and add the URL in the XML structure
    foreach($result as $row) {
      $xmlsitemap .= '
<br><br>
<url><br>
<loc>https://website.com/'. $row['shortUrl'] .'<loc><br>
<changefreq>monthly<changefreq>
<priority>1<priority><br>
<url>

';
    }
  }
```

Comment: All you do with sitemap.xml is to assign the name to a variable you never use. Did you intend to use some XML extension such as [SimpleXML](https://php.net/simplexml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the content of your `$xmlfile` variable to a file.

Try `file_put_contents('sitemap.xml', $xmlfile);` after the `foreach` loop.

But i am wondering whether `<br>` works in xml